# Wrote two short scripts, neither quit

Tags: python

I wrote two short scripts today to do a little housekeeping with my files. One replaces spaces in filenames with underscores and one reads the names of all files and folders in a directory and dumps them into a txt file. However, neither quit. They both end in for loops and I don't know why neither break when they're apparently finished. If I pass quit(), the scripts do what I meant them to do, they just need to be manually aborted.

Here's the underscore adder:

```
import os

pathname = raw_input('Enter the pathname: ')
os.chdir(pathname)
filelist = os.listdir(pathname)
outfile = []
for idx, val in enumerate(filelist):
    outfile.append(val.replace(' ', '_'))
    os.rename(val, outfile[idx])
```

And the directory content reader:

```
import os

pathname = raw_input('What path\'s contents do you want listed? ')
os.chdir(pathname)
filelist = os.listdir(pathname)
file = open('out.txt', 'w')
for idx, val in enumerate(filelist):
        file.write(val + '\n')
```

I assume that since both scripts do very similar things they're not breaking for similar reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: Put a `print` statement in both of those loops. Are you sure that they aren't just running?

Comment: You change to directory `pathname` and then you list the contents of `pathname`.  But presumably these are different directories since you changed directories (unless you're passing only absolute paths?)

Comment: Thanks! The print statement at the end of the loop worked.

Comment: I think that @Blender's comment was a debugging suggestion, rather than a fix.  I think that whatever problem was causing your indefinite loop remains.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, adding a print statement after both for loops breaks out of both. A simple fix. Thanks to Blender for his comment.